# Cassandra not removing deleted rows despite running nodetool compact

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection

Very often I have ghost rows that stay on the server and won't disappear after deleting a row in Cassandra.

I have tried all possible administration options with nodetool (compact, flush, etc.) and also connected to the cluster with jconsole and forced a GC thru it but the rows remain on the cluster.

For testing purpose I updated some rows with a TTL of 0 before doing the DELETE and these rows disappeared completely.

Do I need to live with that or can I somehow trigger a final removal of these deleted rows?

My testcluster uses Cassandra 1.0.7 and has only one single node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phenomenon that you are observing is the result of how distributed deletes work in Cassandra. See the [Cassandra FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#range_ghosts) and the [DistributedDeletes wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DistributedDeletes).

Basically the row will be completely deleted after GCGraceSeconds has passed and a compaction has run.